# How to inject environment variables into CPP file using Visual Code and Platform IO?

Tags: c++, arduino, visual-studio-code, platformio

Just starting with this coming from a JS background.

I am looking into IoT development and wanted to set up my own repo without uploading the SSID and password of my personal WiFi.

Platform IO offers this `platformio.ini` as I understand to set `build_flags`.

```
  build_flags = 
     -D SSID="MySSID"
```

I don't know how to access them from my CPP file though. I want to inject the value from the build flag SSID into my *.cpp file.

```
  #define SSID

  void loop()
  {
    Serial.println(SSID);
  }
```

The above doesn't write anything to the serial monitor.

What am I doing wrong? The code does compile.

Comment: Isn't it a `.cpp` file? You wrote `.ccp` file.

Comment: Yes, it is. I wrote the correct one in the title though.

Comment: From the [documentation](https://docs.platformio.org/en/latest/projectconf/section_env_build.html#build-flags) and this [example](http://blog.cudmore.io/post/2016/02/13/Programming-an-arduino-with-platformio/), the `-D` directives in `build_flags` are translated in the code. So, you just need to define those in `platformio.ini` and then you can use them directly in your code. You don't need to #define them in the code separately.

Comment: Yeah, that is what I understood too. However then Visual Code throws a compile error: `unable to find numeric literal operator 'operator"" FritzBox'

Comment: Right. I believe then it is some kind of configuration problem on part of VS and arduino compiler. You might want to write a different question focused on that problem.

Answer (score 2):

**I know it's been two years, and you've probably moved on from this question. However, for anyone else - like myself - who happens across this from a Google search, here is the answer as I've found it:**

According to [PlatformIO's Dynamic Variables](https://docs.platformio.org/en/latest/projectconf/dynamic_variables.html) page, you correctly define the build variable so that it exists to C++ (as a macro); i.e., `-DSSID="MySSID"`. What you missed, however, is that the values need to be quoted (and potentially escaped): `-DSSID='"MySSID"'` so that when you access the macro in C++ it is a `const char *` string and not an unknown symbol.

See the Warning at the bottom of the page, and note the quotes around the string:

> Be careful with special characters in system environment variables on Unix systems, especially when they are used as the value for preprocessor directives. Symbols like $, &, ~, etc must be explicitly escaped, for example:
>
> `export WIFI_PASS='\"my\~p\&a\\\$\$\$\$word\"'`

It wasn't initially obvious to me either, but it makes sense because the preprocessor will replace `SSID` with whatever you've defined and makes no assumptions about it or its type at all.

Comment: I stumbled across this, thank you. In looking at the [PlatformIO documentation](https://docs.platformio.org/en/stable/projectconf/sections/env/options/build/build_flags.html#stringification) it looks like you actually need to encase the entire build flag in single quotes and only escape any double quotes within the value. So `'-DSSID="MySSID"'`

Answer (score 1):

As @Azeem mentioned, you're redefining the SSID to an empty value. Using preprocessor like this, you must first check if the value exist and if not, assign it a default value.

Here is a simple C++ example:

```
#include <iostream>

#ifndef SSID
#define SSID "(SSID not defined)"
#endif

int main() 
{
    std::cout << "SSID value: " << SSID << std::endl;
    return 0;

}
```

You can compile and run the code with:

```
g++ main.cpp -o main && ./main
```

As you see it prints `(SSID not defined)`.

Now, compiling and running with the following:

```
g++ main.cpp -o main -DSSID='"Hello, World!"' && ./main
```

will output: `SSID value: Hello, World!`

If you want to learn more about preprocessor directives, [cplusplus.com has very nice tutorial](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/preprocessor/)

Also, don't forget to start your `Serial` in `void setup()`.